# Identifying the same company behind stocks traded in different exchanges (e.g. CUSIP and WKN in 1990ies)

Tags: equities, programming, data, historical-data, opensource

I would like to merge two data sources with companies headquartered in Germany between 1980-2000, but listed in Germany and the US. One source identifies "German companies" by their CUSIP, the other one by their WKN. There are names in both data sets, so I can approximately match on name (+ record link on other features). But I thought I could improve on that by matching exactly on (6dig) WKNs and (6dig) CUSIPs?! I guess I would need a resource which has linked stocks of the same company traded in different exchanges? For instance, I am looking for this correspondence

```
Volkswagen AG | WKN = 766400 | CUSIP = 928662
```

Academia no-cost solution required. :/ Thanks.

Edit:

There is OPEN FIGI. But they seem to do poorly on CUSIPs of companies not based in the US (adding 10 or 30 + check digit to CUSIP).

```
curl 'https://api.openfigi.com/v2/mapping' \
--request POST \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data '[{"idType":"ID_CUSIP","idValue":"928662303"}]'
```

Returns `[{"error":"No identifier found."}]`

But `--data '[{"idType":"ID_WERTPAPIER","idValue":"766400"}]'` returns an ID, company name and ticker useful for the matching:

```
[{"data":[{"figi":"BBG000BCH458","name":"VOLKSWAGEN AG","ticker":"VOW","exchCode":"GR","compositeFIGI":"BBG000BCH458","uniqueID":"EQ0011575700001000","securityType":"Common Stock","marketSector":"Equity","shareClassFIGI":"BBG001S67CB7","uniqueIDFutOpt":null,"securityType2":"Common Stock","securityDescription":"VOW"},{"figi":"BBG000BCH4V9","name":"VOLKSWAGEN AG",
```

Any other DB which can identify multinationals (not headquartered in the US) by their CUSIP?